# How to add a text box in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I want to insert a text box below the title in the Table of Contents, as in the picture below:

[image]

I tried to use a `\tcolorbox` in `\addtocontents` but I got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably get an error because what you insert in `\addtocontents` is expanded, and this probably breaks the `tcolorbox`. You need to put what you want inside a robust command, so you don't have to worry too much about expansion.

I'll give an example using `\fbox` and `\parbox`, but it should work the same way with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}% To create a sample document

\begin{document}

% Here you define the robust command, which I named \TOCbox
% This command has to be defined before the call to \tableofcontents
\DeclareRobustCommand\TOCbox{%
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
      \Huge Example text
    }
  }%
  \par
}

% Then you insert it in the .toc file
\addtocontents{toc}{\TOCbox}

\tableofcontents

% dummy document
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

This produces:

> [image]

If you don't want the space between **`Contents`** and the box you can use `\unskip` (if you're using one of the standard classes, otherwise it may nor work):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\TOCbox{%
  \unskip% <- Removes the space after "Contents"
  \vspace{\baselineskip}% A vertical space to unclutter things
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{%
      \Huge Example text
    }
  }%
  \par
}
```